# Dynamic table of Buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to create a dynamically populated two-dimensional array of Button or ImageButton controls.

I want to be able to set the number of buttons in a row.

The table will receive the data from a DataSource control or from code behind, and populate each cell with a Button control with the corresponding value.

For example, if I set then number of columns to 3:

`Value1` `Value2` `Value3`
`Value4` `Value5` `Value6`
`Value7` `Value8`

What ASP.NET control is best for implementing this?
Thank You.

Comment: If you need to repeat horizontally maybe [DataList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatdirection.aspx) is better suited for your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DataList for this. `RepeatColumns` will  help you to set the no. of columns.

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlButtons" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="3">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="button" Text='Your Text' />
    </ItemTemplate>  
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using Repeater Control.

**.aspx Page**

```
<div style="width:269px">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn" Text='<%# Eval("Value") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Here you can set the `width` of div upon your requirment.

**.cs page**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Value");
dt.Rows.Add("Value1");
dt.Rows.Add("Value2");
dt.Rows.Add("Value3");
dt.Rows.Add("Value4");
dt.Rows.Add("Value5");
dt.Rows.Add("Value6");
dt.Rows.Add("Value7");
dt.Rows.Add("Value8");
Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

The output will be look like this

[image]

Comment: Where do you set the number of columns?

Comment: Here the no of columns are automatically set based on the `width` of `div`. If you want to set the the exact no of columns then You can use `DataList` and it has property `RepeatColumns` where you can set the no of columns.